# HTML responsive email stacked columns not working

Tags: email, mobile

I've been trying to get these columns to stack and no solution seems to be working.  There are several layers of nested tables (not all shown here) to keep the structure consistent across clients, but I don't know if this has anything to do with why my columns won't stack. I've tried applying the media queries to td, table, and div elements, but none of the solutions I've read on several sites works.  Below is the gist of my code:

```
<head>
<style>
  table[class="main-table"] {
  width: 625px !important;
  }
  td[class="colsplit"] {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
  }
  table[class="colsplit"] {
    display: block !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    font-size: 12px !important;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table class="main-table" align=center width=625px style="color:#787878; border-spacing:0; border-collapse:collapse; text-decoration:none;" border=0>  
  <!-- Contact Us -->
  <tr>
    <!-- Advertise column -->
    <td class="colsplit" align=left width=50% style="vertical-align:top; padding:0px; margin:0px; display:block;">
      <table class="colsplit" width=100% style="border-color:orange; border-width:5px; border-style:solid;">
        <tr>
          <td class="colsplit" align=left style="color:#787878; font-size:16px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif; font-weight:bold; margin:0px; padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;">Advertise
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="colsplit" style="vertical-align:top; color:#787878; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif; margin:0px; padding:0px 0px 10px 10px;">To advertise in our newsletter, please email:
            <br>
            <a href="mailto:email@domain.com" style="color:#333333; text-decoration:none;"><strong>email@domain.com</strong>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <!-- Advertise column close -->
    <!-- Services column -->
    <td class="colsplit" align=left width=50% style="vertical-align:top; padding:0px; margin:0px; display:block;">
      <table class="colsplit" align=left width=100% style="border-color:orange; border-width:5px; border-style:solid;">
        <tr>
          <td class="colsplit" style="color:#787878; font-size:16px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif; font-weight:bold; margin:0px; padding:0px 20px 10px 0px;">Newsletter Services
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="colsplit" style="vertical-align:top; color:#787878; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif; margin:0px; padding:0px 20px 10px 0px;">Interested in reading more?
            <br>Click the link below to
            <br>
            <a href="http://links.email.dmnews.com/ctt?kn=10&ms=MTI0NDc1MTgS1&r=MjE1MTE3OTc2ODc0S0&b=3&j=NjIxMzY0NDMzS0&mt=1&rt=0" name="DMNregister" style="color:#333333; text-decoration: none;"><strong>Sign Up for Our Newsletters</strong>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="colsplit" style="vertical-align:top; color:#787878; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif; margin:0px; padding:0px 20px 10px 0px;">If you no longer wish to receive this newsletter, click here to
            <br>
            <a href="http://www.pages05.net/haymarketmediagrouplimited/DirectMarketingNews/dmnunsubscribe?spMailingID=12447518&spUserID=MjE1MTE3OTc2ODc0S0&spJobID=NjIxMzY0NDMzS0&spReportId=NjIxMzY0NDMzS0" name="Unsubscribe" style="color:#333333; text-decoration: none;" target="_blank" xt="LPWEBFORMOPTIN" xtwebform="1740515"><strong>unsubscribe</strong>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="colsplit" style="vertical-align:top; color:#787878; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans Serif; margin:0px; padding:0px 20px 10px 0px;">To manage your account and Newsletter settings, click here for
            <br>
            <a href="http://links.email.dmnews.com/ctt?kn=8&ms=MTI0NDc1MTgS1&r=MjE1MTE3OTc2ODc0S0&b=3&j=NjIxMzY0NDMzS0&mt=1&rt=0" name="ManageAccount" style="color:#333333; text-decoration:none;"><strong>My Account</strong>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <!-- Services column close -->
  </tr>
  <!-- Contact Us close -->
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: A table's columns will not stack. It is notoriously difficult to work with tables as they do not respect most CSS.

Comment: Depending on where your email gets displayed, `<style>` elements might be filtered out. Inline your styles instead. (There’s tools for that, by mailchimp etc.)

Comment: The stacking is for a mobile-responsive design.  I've been designing HTML emails for quite a while, so I know how to navigate all the quirks for every desktop client.  My problem is that when mobile devices shrink the email to fit the screen, one of my tables with multiple columns and small text becomes so tiny that it's illegible, or the columns become squeezed together and it looks ugly.  I keep reading post after post about how people have managed to get their table columns to stack, but I must be missing something because it's not working for me.